# How to get last N connected edges

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm writing a large scale chat application and here is my db schema:

```
CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY User.name STRING;

CREATE CLASS Message EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Message.text STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY Message.createdAt DATETIME;
CREATE INDEX Message.createdAt ON Message(createdAt) NOTUNIQUE;

CREATE CLASS Send EXTENDS E;
```

i'm using lightweight edges and i have 200,000 edges connected to `#12:0` like this:

```
CREATE VERTEX User SET name = 'john';
/* #12:0 */

CREATE VERTEX Message SET content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', createdAt = SYSDATE();
/* #20:0 */

CREATE EDGE Send FROM #12:0 TO #20:0
```

i want to get last 5 messages that connected to the `#12:0`. i tried these queries:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT FROM (
  SELECT EXPAND(OUT('Send')) FROM #12:0
) ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 5
```

it took ~2s

"explain" result:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@version": 0,
            "documentReads": 200000,
            "current": "#19:66661",
            "recordReads": 200000,
            "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 377,
            "expandElapsed": 0,
            "orderByElapsed": 5,
            "evaluated": 200000,
            "elapsed": 2416.7283,
            "resultType": "collection",
            "resultSize": 5,
            "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,current=x,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,expandElapsed=l,orderByElapsed=l,evaluated=l,elapsed=f"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 2.427 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT OUT('Send')[199994-199999] FROM #12:0
```

it took ~6s

"explain" result:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@version": 0,
            "documentReads": 1,
            "current": "#12:0",
            "recordReads": 1,
            "optimizationElapsed": 0,
            "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 8749,
            "evaluated": 1,
            "elapsed": 8749.445,
            "resultType": "collection",
            "resultSize": 1,
            "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,current=x,recordReads=l,optimizationElapsed=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,evaluated=l,elapsed=f"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 8.759 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

is there any faster way to do this?

*please don't refer to the [chat use case](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Chat-use-case.html)...*

*i'm using orientdb 2.2.7*

Comment: Hi, can you do the explain of your query by pressing the explain button,please? Thx in advance

Comment: Can you try this `SELECT EXPAND(OUT('Send')) FROM #12:0 ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 5` and tell me if is a little bit faster or not? Thx in advance

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi, i've added "explain" results.
your query is a bit faster (~0.5s faster), but still it took ~1.8s

Comment: Why are you against http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Chat-use-case.html?

Comment: @Lvca i'm not against it, it's a good idea, but i have a lot of chat rooms and it requires extra code to manage multiple DBs.
i have some questions about that, i will ask later (_for example: in my program, i need to know **when** the database reach to the maximum numbers of clusters and then create new database._)
i want to try other solutions before i decide…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! i find a fast way to do this.

I've change my db schema to:

```
CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY User.name STRING;

CREATE CLASS Message;
CREATE PROPERTY Message.text STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY Message.writer LINK User;
CREATE PROPERTY Message.createdAt DATETIME;
CREATE INDEX Message.writer ON Message(writer) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX;
CREATE INDEX Message.createdAt ON Message(createdAt) NOTUNIQUE;
```

I'm using `Message.writer` to connect to the `User` instead of using edge.

**Query:**

```
SELECT FROM Message
WHERE createdAt < sysdate() AND writer = #12:0
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
SKIP 10 LIMIT 5
```

this takes ~30ms on 1.5 million records!

**IMPORTANT:** Notice the `createdAt < sysdate()` in `WHERE` clause,
you have to write a dummy condition on the `ORDER BY` field, this makes `ORDER BY` to use `createdAt` index (~700ms faster)

"explain" result (with `createdAt < sysdate()`):

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@version": 0,
            "documentReads": 252,
            "fullySortedByIndex": true,
            "documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass": 252,
            "recordReads": 252,
            "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 6,
            "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": true,
            "compositeIndexUsed": 1,
            "current": "#49:1493348",
            "involvedIndexes": [
                "Message.createdAt"
            ],
            "limit": 5,
            "evaluated": 252,
            "elapsed": 6.447579,
            "resultType": "collection",
            "resultSize": 5,
            "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,compositeIndexUsed=l,current=x,involvedIndexes=e,evaluated=l,user=x,elapsed=f"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.032 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

"explain" result (without `createdAt < sysdate()`):

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@version": 0,
            "documentReads": 48512,
            "fullySortedByIndex": false,
            "documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass": 48512,
            "recordReads": 48512,
            "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 801,
            "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": false,
            "compositeIndexUsed": 1,
            "current": "#49:1499971",
            "involvedIndexes": [
                "Message.writer"
            ],
            "limit": 5,
            "orderByElapsed": 49,
            "evaluated": 48512,
            "elapsed": 853.48004,
            "resultType": "collection",
            "resultSize": 5,
            "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,compositeIndexUsed=l,current=x,involvedIndexes=e,orderByElapsed=l,evaluated=l,user=x,elapsed=f"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.864 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```